# Demonstrating simple joins in pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas

I am working out a syllabus for teaching some colleagues pandas and SQL and want to demonstrate an SQL join and then how one might do a similar join using pandas.

**My SQL query:**

```
SELECT    
town.id,
town.name,
county.name AS county,
nation.name AS nation
FROM town
LEFT JOIN county ON county.id = town.county_id
LEFT JOIN nation ON nation.id = county.nation_id;
```

The documentation for df.join() and df.merge() are somewhat confusing me. Could someone explain how I can perform the same join in pandas with data from the following queries. **I want to left join county on town.county_id.**

**town:**

```
SELECT    
town.id,
town.name,
town.county_id
FROM town
```

**county:**

```
SELECT    
county.id,
county.name,
county.nation_id
FROM county
```

**nation:**

```
SELECT    
nation.id,
nation.name
FROM nation
```

I have tried a couple of approaches but I get weird results. This one looks the most promising but I get a weird output.

```
output = pd.merge(
  town, 
  county, 
  left_on='id', 
  right_on='county_id'
)
```

output:

```
    name_x nuts_region_x  county_id_x          name_y nuts_region_y  county_id_y
0     Aaron's Hill    South East            1    Aaron's Hill    South East            1
1     Aaron's Hill    South East            1      Abbey Mead    South East            1
...            ...           ...          ...             ...           ...          ...
1795      Aberdeen      Scotland           39          Ashton      Scotland           96
1796      Aberdeen      Scotland           39      Auchenback      Scotland           96
```

Any help much appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: you did Ok! note that because you have the same columns name twice (town and county), pandas added ```'_x'``` and ```'_y'``` to the column name. if you want to avoid that just give a different name for each column like: ```town_name``` and ```county_name```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the following:

```
town_query = """
    SELECT    
    town.id,
    town.name,
    town.nuts_region,
    town.county_id
    FROM town
"""

county_query = """
    SELECT    
    county.id,
    county.name AS county_name,
    county.nation_id 
    FROM county
"""

nation_query = """
    SELECT    
    nation.id,
    nation.name AS nation_name
    FROM nation
"""
```

We need to set the index to be the id column. Then Pandas will automatically use it for the join.

```
town = pd.read_sql_query(town_query, database_connection).set_index("id")
county = pd.read_sql_query(county_query, database_connection).set_index("id")
nation = pd.read_sql_query(nation_query, database_connection).set_index("id")
```

This double merge did the trick and gave me a nice output.

```
output = town.merge(
  county,
  left_on='county_id',
  right_index=True,
  suffixes=('_town', '_county')
).merge(
  nation,
  left_on='nation_id',
  right_index=True,
  suffixes=('_county', '_nation')
)
```

output:

```
                name  nuts_region  county_id  county_name  nation_id  nation_name
id                                                                               
1       Aaron's Hill   South East          1       Surrey          1      England
25        Abbey Mead   South East          1       Surrey          1      England
54        Abbotswood   South East          1       Surrey          1      England
160   Abinger Bottom   South East          1       Surrey          1      England
161   Abinger Common   South East          1       Surrey          1      England
...              ...          ...        ...          ...        ...          ...
2677         Andreas  Isle of Man         81  Isle of Man          5  Isle of Man
3991         Agneash  Isle of Man         81  Isle of Man          5  Isle of Man
4474         Andreas  Isle of Man         81  Isle of Man          5  Isle of Man
5788         Agneash  Isle of Man         81  Isle of Man          5  Isle of Man
6271         Andreas  Isle of Man         81  Isle of Man          5  Isle of Man
```